# How to solve duplicate column name exception in @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to @JoinColumn two entities, named Customer and Account. One customer can have multiple accounts, so I thought it was right to use @OneToMany in Customer entity. and @ManyToOne in Account entity. However, it keeps giving me the Duplicate column name in the console. 
It can be solved by changing the variable name, but I cannot simply change it, because hibernate will not find the column name in the DB. Even adding @Column name attribute won't work.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I have tried following:

- change the owner entity. I put @JoinColumn in Account entity instead <- not working
- change the variable name. <- create another error SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
- try with @OneToOne instead. <- it worked, but since multiple account number retrieved, then result set cannot be mapped
- follow the right way as in example, but duplicate mapping exception is not solved.
- change the @Id position. <- it works but its not what I expected.

I have tried the SQL query in DB. The query is work, but I have no idea how to map it in hibernate jpa.

Oracle Query

```sql
SELECT a.USR_ID, a.USR_MGNT_NO, a.CUST_NO, a.ACCT_STATUS,
        b.ACCT_SEQ, b.ACCT_NO, b.CUST_NO, b.CUST_NM, b.SBJ_CD, b.ACCT_PRD_NM
FROM LB_USR_BASE a LEFT OUTER JOIN
 LB_ACCT_BASE b ON
a.CUST_NO=b.CUST_NO
WHERE a.USR_MGNT_NO=:usrMgtNo;
```

Customer Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Customer implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String custNo;

    private String usrId;
    private String usrMgntNo;
    private String acctStatus;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "custNo")
    private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();


}
```

Account Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String acctId;
    private String acctNo;

    @ManyToOne
    private UsrBase user;
    private String sbjCd;
    private String custNo;

}
```

Repository

```java
public interface CustAcctRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, String>{

    List<Customer> findAcctByUsrMgntNo(String usrMgntNo);

}
```

Service/ Controller

```java
List<Customer> tes = CustAcctRepo.findAcctByUsrMgntNo("12345"));
```

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [ACCOUNT] contains physical column name [cust_no] referred to by multiple physical column names: [cust_no], [custNo]
```

==========

## **EDIT:**

I modified both entities, as follow:

```java
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String acctSeq;
    private String acctNo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "custNo",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UsrBase user;

}
```

and

```java
public class Customer implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String custNo;

    private String usrId;
    private String usrMgntNo;
    private String acctStatus;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AcctBase> accounts = new HashSet<AcctBase>();


}
```

Comment: Remove the field `custNo` from `Account`: you already have the ManyToOne which is mapped to the same column, and `custNo` is thus redundant. And move the JoinColumn annotation to the `user` field in Account. Customer.accounts is the inverse side, and should thus not define the mapping of the associated, since it's **mapped by** Account.user.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your assistance. I've removed custNo from Account. I've moved the JoinColumn to user field also. Still the same duplicate mapping exception appeared

Answer (score 0):

See, In below code you are creating mapping with two fields : 'user' and 'custNo'. Either map with user or with Account.custNo

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
@JoinColumn(name = "custNo")
private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
```

Comment: sorry my mistake.. I have removed custNo now, but still the same error appeared

Comment: for field custNo, what is corresponding column name in bot tables and can you share setter method also.

Comment: I think the DB design is wrong from the beginning (I just use legacy DB). there is no FK to connect both, but I used custNo as the connector. custNo is relatable, but this field is not set as FK. in Customer table, the PK is usrId, but if I put `@Id` in usrId field, the where query will be Select * from ... where Customer.usrId = Account.usrId, which is unavailable. For the Setter method, I use Lombok, so I didnt set any Get Set method, just put some annotation `@Data`, `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor`